# Get value of select input based on checkbox selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two checkboxes and a form(three select inputs) - `name`,`phone` and `address`.
If `first checkbox` is selected - `name` and `phone` will be displayed and if `second checkbox` is selected - `address` will be displayed.

Form:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" class="disableCiti" /> First

    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" class="citiInput" /> Second

    <form id="f1">
    <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="first">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="john" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="12345" required>
    </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="berlin" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Jquery:

```
    var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
        form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
        check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
        check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

    check1.onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked){
        document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
    }
    }

    check2.onchange = function() {
        if(this.checked){
        document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
        document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
    }
    }
```

css:

```
    .hidden {
    display: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/tg4Lokz6/3/

I want to get the values of the selected checkbox. If `first checkbox` is selected - get values of `name and phone` and if `second checkbox` is selcted - get values of `address`

What i have tried:

```
   var name = $("#name").val();
```

But how to get only checked values?

Comment: How and where you wan to get the values? There is no button or anything that says get value or something.

Comment: Yeah i forgot to add a button. It can be button - onclick().

Comment: I have added a solution using plain javascript. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an attribute selector:

```
var name1 = $('input[name="checkbox1"]:checked').val();
var name2 = $('input[name="checkbox2"]:checked').val();
```

Another approach:

```
if ($('#checkbox1').prop("checked"))
var name1 = $("#checkbox1").val();
if ($('#checkbox2').prop("checked"))
var name2 = $("#checkbox2").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

So first, add a button to the UI like:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
   <button id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Get Checked Values</button>
</div>
```

and then add a `addEventListener` for this button like:

```
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    // Our code logic here...
});
```

Inside this, we just need to check if either `check1` or `check2` is checked and based on that get respective element values like:

```
if (check2.checked) {
    // If second checkbox is selcted - get values of `address`
    text = document.querySelector("#address").value

} else if (check1.checked){
    // If first checkbox is selected - get values of `name` and `phone` 
    text = document.querySelector("#name").value + ', '
    text += document.querySelector("#phone").value
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
  form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
  check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
  check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

check1.onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#address").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
  }
}

check2.onchange = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#name").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest('.form-group').style.display = "";
  }
}

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
 e.preventDefault()
  console.clear()
  var text = '';
  if (check2.checked) {
    text = document.querySelector("#address").value
  } else if (check1.checked){
   text = document.querySelector("#name").value + ', '
    text += document.querySelector("#phone").value
  }  
  console.log(text)
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox1">First</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbox2">Second</label>
</div>
<form id="f1">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="first">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="name" name="name" value="john" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="phone" name="phone" value="12345" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="address" name="address" value="berlin" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <button id="btn" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Get Checked Values</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code to get value inside the `if()` statement, and also check the other approach I do in the second snippet:

```js
var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
  form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
  check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
  check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

check1.onchange = function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#address").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "none";
    let name = $("#name").val();
    let phone = $("#phone").val();
    console.log(name, phone);
    
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#address").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "";
  }
};

check2.onchange = function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#name").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "none";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "none";
    let address = $("#address").val();
    console.log(address);
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#name").closest(".form-group").style.display = "";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest(".form-group").style.display = "";
  }
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" class="disableCiti" /> First

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" class="citiInput" /> Second

<form id="f1">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="first">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="john" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="12345" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="berlin" required>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Another approach I suggest that you use radio button:

```js
var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
  form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
  check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
  check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

check1.onchange = function () {
  document.querySelector("#name").closest(".form-group").style.display = "block";
      document.querySelector("#phone").closest(".form-group").style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector("#address").closest(".form-group").style.display = "none";
  if (this.checked) {
    let name = $("#name").val();
    let phone = $("#phone").val();
    console.log(name, phone);
  }
};

check2.onchange = function () {
  document.querySelector("#name").closest(".form-group").style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest(".form-group").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector("#address").closest(".form-group").style.display = "block";
  if (this.checked) {
    document.querySelector("#name").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "none";
    document.querySelector("#phone").closest(".form-group").style.display =
      "none";
    let address = $("#address").val();
    console.log(address);
  }
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="dynamicFields" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" class="disableCiti" /> First

<br />

<input type="radio" name="dynamicFields" id="checkbox2" value="2" class="citiInput" /> Second

<form id="f1">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="first">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="john" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" value="12345" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" value="berlin" required>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually checkbox values are boolean values, you can check if the checkbox is checked;

```
var isChecked = document.getElementById('elementName').checked;
```

As a result 'isChecked' variable has the true/false you need.